# Lost on the inputshape (Tensorflow.js LSTM model attempt)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to play with my first LSTM model on Tensorflow.js, but I'm pretty much stuck on the shapes (I think)

Assuming the Input array:

```
X = [ [
    0,
    0.0013304822998336796,
    0.0015680684248040588,
    0.000617723924922986,
    0.002708481824661435,
    0.0035162746495605024,
    -0.00009503444998804067,
    -0.004941791399382223,
    -0.0030886196246138198,
    0.0010928961748635224
  ],
  [
    0,
    0.00023727044084842497,
    -0.0007118113225452749,
    0.0013761685569213533,
    0.0021828880558061314,
    -0.0014236226450907719,
    -0.006263939638399774,
    -0.00441323019978157,
    -0.00023727044084842497,
    0.0033692402600484783
  ], ... ]
```

and output array:

```
Y = [
  [ 0.0028556470420255664 ],
  [ 0.006330620210385884 ],
  [ -0.0029661016949151797 ],
  ...
]
```

Building the Tensors like:

```
const xs = tf.tensor2d(X, [X.length, X[0].length]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d(Y, [Y.length, 1]);
```

then the model and it's training like:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units: 10, inputShape: [10] }));
model.add(tf.layers.dropout({rate: 0.25}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1 }));
model.add(tf.layers.activation({ activation: 'linear' }));

model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: 'meanAbsoluteError'
});

model.fit(xs, ys, {
    batchSize: 4, epochs: 50, callbacks: {
        onEpochEnd: async (epoch, log) => {
            console.log("Epoch: ", epoch, " - ", log);
        }
    }
});
```

Keek getting the error `"Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_LSTM1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2"` ..... tryed changing the inputShape to something else, not giving error before the training, but giving a diferent error `"Error when checking input: expected lstm_LSTM1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 168418,10"` on train..... So I'm assuming I'm all wrong anyway with the shape somehow lol this is a model I tryed to migrate to .js from python, It is exactly what I need, but on the wrong language..... the original model in python is:

```
def build_lstm_model(input_data, output_size=1, neurons=20, activ_func='linear', dropout=0.25, loss='mae', optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=( input_data.shape[1], input_data.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(units=output_size))
    model.add(Activation(activ_func))
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
```

and the training:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=4)
```

What is exactly the "inputShape" on my situation? Are the tensors formed the wrong way? What am I missing?

Thank you, I was really looking forward to get this working, and understanding why it's not working. To get my hands dirty on Machine Learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input shape` of `keras.layers.LSTM` is (batch size, time step, features). As you can see, the RNN structure was made for time depend data, so if your data contains no time information, better not using it. On the other hand, if you do have a **time information**, then be sure your input shape is a 3d(batch size + time step and features = 1 + 2) input. If you don't set the batch size, keras will set it to `None` which serve as `batch size=1`, so never mind if you didn't set it up. **In your case**, you just use `inputShape: [10]` which is not the format for using `keras.layers.LSTM`. **If you would like to try applying LSTM anyway**, expand the dimension for your input, and don't forget the change the inputShape following with you change.

Comment: Thank you, got me on the right path! Just not 100% sure yet, because of some concepts like batch_size and timesteps, will try around with the information you gave me....... should I use timestamp or datestring as the "time steps" and being timestamp, also normalized?

It really needs to be LSTM, based on the example I'm following.

Comment: Imagine you got array which is like ```[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]``` and it is a 2d array with feature in time1 is ```[1, 2, 3]``` and time2 is ```[4, 5, 6]``` you can guess the RNN output(pred time3) will be ```[7, 8, 9]```. It's the basic idea to use ```keras.layers.LSTM```. Normalisation is not always needed while in most of the deep learning model, it's better to do that. **Just try to modify it and have fun**